# PHP with dropdown selection

Tags: php

I have list of items in my dropdown. Now I wish to select item according to database value. Suppose I have list of cities their are nearly 300 cities. I have city value as new jersey in my record. Now while editing form checking each options is not possible for 300 options. Like

```
<option value="A" <? if ($a="A") echo "selected"; ?> >A</option>
<option value="B" <? if ($a="B") echo "selected"; ?> >B</option>
<option value="C" <? if ($a="C") echo "selected"; ?> >C</option>
<option value="D" <? if ($a="D") echo "selected"; ?> >D</option>
<option value="E" <? if ($a="E") echo "selected"; ?> >E</option>
<option value="F" <? if ($a="F") echo "selected"; ?> >F</option>
<option value="G" <? if ($a="G") echo "selected"; ?> >G</option>
<option value="H" <? if ($a="H") echo "selected"; ?> >H</option>
```

Isn't any way to minimise for 300 records. Can't I write short code for this?

** NOTE My options values are not stored in array.**

Comment: How are you building the options dynamically via a for loop ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

suppose your values are stored in an array called `$options`, you could write something like this:

```
foreach($options as $option)
{
  echo "<option value=\"$option\"";
  if($option == $a)
  {
    echo ' selected="selected"';
  }
  echo ">$option</option>";
}
```

Comment: @RahulSingh If your values come from a pre-defined range, such as A-Z, then you could replace `$options` with the `range()` function mentioned in @GhazanfarMir's answer

Comment: if your values do not originate from a range, you could pre-load your options array like this: `$options = array('myval1', 'myval2', ...);`

Answer (score 0):

you should use [loops](http://www.google.md/search?q=php%20loops) for output

like

```
$result = mysql_query('select id, city from cities');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<option value=' . $row['id'] . (($row['city'] == 'new jersey') ? 'selected' : '') . " >" . $row['city'] . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: Why don't you understand my option values are stored in array?

Comment: you got nice answer above from hair raisin, use it

Answer (score 0):

Try [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function in php:

```
<?php foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $letter){?>
   <option value="<?php echo $letter?>" <? if ($a==$letter) echo "selected='selected'"; ?> ><?php echo $letter?></option>
<?php }?>
```

Change the range accordingly. You could use this function with integers too.

Comment: That means for alphabetical series A-Z first I have to store these values in $letter thinking it as array?

Comment: No.. `range()` function will loop from A-Z storing one letter at a time on each iteration.

Comment: but wha would be if I HAVE names in options,, like Ghazanfar,rahul than how will it range/.